# Maximum Velocity of Bob Confusion (SHM)

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics

So I am asked to find the net force acting on the bob when it is travelling at maximum speed.
The maximum speed is 1.17m/s.

My first thought is that when the bob is travelling at maximum speed, the acceleration is zero.
So F=ma, F=0.

My second thought was to use the centripetal force formula, (F=(mv^2)/r) (in this case r is 2m and m is 0.2kg) and I got an answer of 0.137N.

Which way is correct?

Comment: Is this a pendulum or a spring and mass system?

Comment: @nasu it's a pendulum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although the bob may be travelling at maximum speed, its acceleration is not zero because the *direction* of its velocity is changing.